How can I solve invalid dependencies problem with g++?
While practicing compiling cpp into dll, I encountered the following problem

My Window bit is 64
Here is cpp code that compiled:
#include <iostream>

extern "C" {
    __declspec(dllexport) int firstDll(int coercivity) {
        return 1 + coercivity;
    }
}


Compile command is:
g++ -shared -o Te.dll Te.cpp
And I drop Te.dll into DependenciesGui, and I found out that there was no dependencies:
ext-ms-win-oobe-query-l1-1-0.dll
I think my cpp code is very simple, Cannot understand there is no required dll
How can I solve this problem?
Should I download that dll?
Please Help.

My Java program with JNA like this:
Te.java
package maven.te;

import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;

public interface Te extends Library {
    Te inst = Native.load("Te", Te.class);
    int firstDll(int coercivity);
}

Run.java
package maven.te;

public class Run {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int result = Te.inst.firstDll(5);
        System.out.println(result);
    }

}


Program make Exception that:
java.lang.unsatisfiedlinkerror %1 is not a valid win32 application

Did you actually try to use your Te.dll from a test exe ?

by that document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/apiindex/windows-apisets#api-set-contract-names the dependencies that start with ext are extensions that may not be present run time, so the dll should run

@wohlstad I ran the JNA java program to call Te.dll
The program has occur Exception that java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'Te'

@ÖöTiib But the loading Te.dll was faill..
Exception msg is
java.lang.unsatisfiedlinkerror %1 is not a valid win32 application

@powerfulH Then take a step back and try to run the dll from C++. Issue may be between dll and java, not in that ext dll.

How do you load the DLL? What is your Java-code doing?

The message is typically produced when you have an ABI miss-match 64-bit Java trying to load a 32-bit DLL or the other way around.
